differential gain for mismatched \$g_m\$ in differential amplifiers
I couldn't understand how the author came up with the expression of differential mode gain. He states to look from the Fig 4.17 to derive this expression, whereas the fig 4.17 has no mention of \$R_{ss}\$ in it.
How do I come up with this differential mode expression?
Edit: I actually have \$R_{ss}\$ figured out, with it being the current source resistance. I've also made progress in deriving that expression, by taking \$V_{in1}\$ = \$\Delta\ V\$ and \$V_{in2}\$ = \$-\Delta\ V\$ and using superposition theorem to calculate the differential output, but I'm not getting anywhere close to the expression given in the book.



ah sorry forgot to mention it, its Design of CMOS Analog Inegrated Circuits by B, Razavi

It may be differential gain also called Ad. CMRR is defined as  |$ \frac {Ad} {A_{CM}} $|. $ A_{CM}$ is common mode gain.

I don't have the book and therefore I'm not reading it. But $R_{\text{SS}}$, from past reading on my part, is usually meant as a resistance that is taken to be parallel to the ideal current source $I{_\text{SS}}$. This makes the ideal source non-ideal. Doesn't the book cover this???

@periblepsis yes it does, but considering that as well if I calculate the A_dm, it comes nowhere close to what the book has stated. I'm somehow not able to figure out how the author came with that relation.

@wolff I was only addressing myself to your comment "fig 4.17 has no mention of $R_{_\text{SS}}$ in it." If you already knew what it meant, then perhaps you could have said so. I assume also that your $g_{m_1}=g_m+\frac12\Delta g_m$ and that $g_{m_2}=g_m-\frac12\Delta g_m$. Anyway, it's late right now and I don't have time to read with more understanding right now. I'm leaving this to others for the moment.

@wolff I also am not sure, just glancing, at the +1 term. Drawing not from memory (which isn't reliable anyway) and only going from mental models in my head at this moment, I can quickly see that CMRR=$\frac{g_m}{\Delta g_m},2,g_m,R_{_\text{SS}}$ without grounding on one side. Your textbook has another term there. This may be due to the grounding of that one side. But I'm tired. So I'll come back to it tomorrow if someone else hasn't bothered. I'm a discrete device hobbyist. From that perspective, I tend to very much hate mosfets in linear circuits...

@periblepsis my bad i should've mentioned it, I'll edit that right away.

ah finally. its done, finally ended up with the right expression, thankyou all for the insights. I'm new here so should I delete the question or leave it as it is since my query is resolved?

@periblepsis You have peaked my interest. This might not be the correct place to ask this, but I'm wondering what you mean with: "I'm a discrete device hobbyist. From that perspective, I tend to very much hate mosfets in linear circuits." Why are BJT's better from a discrete perspective "more likeable" than mosfets?

@Carl The context is for linear circuits (audio amplifiers, for example) and discrete designs. Also, just by the way, I bought a bevy of BJTs in TO-92 packages (about 22,000 of them) at 0.4 cents each. I've never been exposed to an opportunity for such a cheap collection of mosfets. Not even close. So BJTs are also much cheaper, as well. But the main point has to do with trying to use them, not as switches, but as linear amplifier stages. I much prefer and enjoy BJTs for that purpose.
